# Compare Non-Reified Types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to compare two `Type` objects for equality, *disregarding their type parameters*.

For example, comparing `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<string>` returns **false**, which makes sense, but I just want to compare the `IEnumerable` element.

How can I do this with `Type` or `TypeInfo`?

Comment: Just a terminology note, for an easier time connecting with the C# community: we call reified types "closed" and non-reified types "open". See ECMA-334 25.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();` to get the Generic base type.

Comment: And if you need to compare arbitrary types that may or may not be generic, check `GetType().IsGenericType` before calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`, as it throws for non-generic types.